# Relationship between Intrinsic Dimension and Principal Components - PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a data space with 144 features 12x12 grid :

[image]

and I know that I can fully describe it in M = 6 features with the help of PCA. My data space has intrinsic dimensionality = 3 (three grades of freedom : rotation ,  vertical and horizontal translation).

The question is : Is M going to be equal to the number of intrinsic dimensions? Is there a relationship between my subspace of M and his intrinsic dimension ?